# "Undefined" error when passing params to another screen in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have 2 screens, EditProfile and Profile. I'm trying to pass the edited name and date from EditProfile to Profile. They are both stacked in a ProfileNavigator, Profile is the first screen that appears and from there, user can tap on a edit profile button and navigate to Edit Profile Screen. How can i pass updated Edit Screen name and date params to main profile? Following code does not work and return Cannot read property "date" of undefined:

```
    const EditProfileScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    }
    
     return (
    ..
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.commandButton} onPress= {() => {navigation.navigate("Profile",  {params: {date: date, name: name }})} }
        
        activeOpacity={0.5}>
              <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Submit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

While this is the code for the Profile Screen:

```
    const ProfileScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    
      const { date } = route.params;
      const { name } = route.params;
    
      return (
    ..
    <Text>{JSON.stringify(date)}</Text>
    <Text>{JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach, but you are missing null handling for the initial render of the profile screen.

Think like this, the first time you navigate to the profile screen there wont be a route.params as you are not passing any parameters which ends up in an error.

But when you move to the edit screen and come back with parameters you will have the route.params which you can access without any issues.

So change your code like this

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(route.params?.date)}</Text>
    <Text>{JSON.stringify(route.params?.name)}</Text>
```

Or if you have the profile object in the state of the profile screen, update it using a useEffect hook based on the change of route.params.

Comment: thanks, edited the Text component by replacing it with route.params?.date but it still throws the same error, do you have any clue why?

Comment: Did you remove the const { date } = route.params; , you should remove those two lines

Comment: @Tony have a look at the docs, it may help you with the example https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

Comment: Now the error is gone but it shows no name in Profile Screen, why?

Comment: What happens when you go to edit screen and come back? and do you have the initial name and date somewhere in a state ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear i'm a beginner, i should set an initial name in Profile too same as i have in Edit Profile, but i don't know how to do :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237284/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-tony).